# list of countries with 2 or more official languages that have 2 times more unofficial languages

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have task with the next model:

[image: DB model]

Task is next: Output a list of countries with two or more official languages, in which the number of unofficial languages is at least twice that of official languages.

The task seems quite simple, but I have an errors with it.
I tried next:

```
SELECT name, countrylanguage.*
FROM country, countrylanguage
WHERE countrycode = code AND isofficial LIKE "t"
GROUP BY isofficial 
HAVING COUNT(*) => 2;
```

But I have only one entry back.

To list all of the countries with more than 2 official languages:

```
SELECT country.name
FROM country
JOIN countrylanguage
ON countrycode = code
WHERE isofficial = 't'
GROUP BY country.name
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

But how should I select only countries with twice more unofficial languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
select * from (
  SELECT
    countrycode, 
    sum(case when isofficial = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as officials,
    sum(case when isofficial = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as nonofficials
  FROM countrylanguage
  GROUP BY countrycode 
) X
where officials >= 2 and nonofficials > officials * 2
```

Comment: ERROR 1630 (42000): FUNCTION world.SUM does not exist.

Comment: ok, this error was just because MySQL does not accept spaces between function name and parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Inner queries seem the simplest approach. Start with a list of countries with at least two official languages:

```
select countrycode, count(1)
from countrylangauge
where isofficial
group by countrycode
having count(1) >= 2
```

Joining with a similar query allows getting unofficial language counts

```
select official.countrycode, 
       official.number 'Official Langs',
       unofficual.number 'Unofficual Langs'
from (select countrycode, count(1) as number
      from countrylangauge
      where isofficial
      group by countrycode
      having count(1) >= 2
     ) offical
   inner join (select countrycode, count(1) as number
      from countrylangauge
      where not isofficial
      group by countrycode
      -- Since min count of offical is 2, and need double unoffical
      -- then need at lease 4 here
      having count(1) >= 4
     ) unoffical
     on unofficual.countrycode = offical.countrycode
          and unofficual.number >= 2*officual.countrycode
```

Feel free to join to `country` to get more details of the counry.